# React app won't run after npm fix audit --force

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, chakra-ui

I installed react-scroll library via 'npm install react-scroll' and after that I also run 'npm fix audit --force' to fix some vulnerabilities. That results in my app not running again. I tried some fixes here still struggling to fix the issue. I need help .

I tried pasting this

`const crypto = require("crypto"); const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash; crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);`

in node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js

Now the app is saying it cannot compile

Answer (score 0):

I got an error called "This site can't be reached" after executing `npm fix audit --force` when installing Ant Design into VS Code. So, I tried a couple of things but none of them worked.

- The used Environment is Node.js and the Library is React.

So, I downgraded the Node.js to version 16 and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Share the solution, others can learn it too.

Comment: Alright done that

Comment: @BuhariAminuAdam Did you run the `npm run build`?

Comment: No I only removed the node_modules folder and run npm install. Everything is back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution I found which fixed the problem is to remove the node_modules folder and run `npm install`.